# django get_or_create depending on result from a custom manager method

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement a safe method of creating instances of the model `Bar`. I have a custom manager method to search for any nearby existing `Bar` instances based on a `x, y` pair of coordinates: `Bar.objects.circle_search(x, y, radius)`

These `x, y` values typically come from `Foo`. Upon creating a `Foo` instance it should then be associated via a foreign key with an existing `Bar` instance if `Foo.x, Foo.y` are within `radius` of `Bar.x, Bar.y`. If no `Bar` instances are found then create one. Each `Bar` instance has `x, y` columns that are defined by the `Foo` that created it.

I had something simple like:

```
bar = Bar.objects.circle_search(foo.x, foo.y, radius)
if bar is None:
    # fill some kwargs
    bar, created = Bar.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
```

however there is an obvious race here where two nearby `foo`'s could create separate `Bar` instances that are close to each other (there shouldn't be any `Bar` instances within `radius` of each other).

Is there anyway to chain/insert the `circle_search` method to be used as the `get` part of `get_or_create`? i.e. in plain English - get a `Bar` that matches the `circle_search`, if not then create one.

```
# something like?
Bar.object.get_or_create(circle_search(foo.x, foo.y, radius), **kwargs)
```

The problem is that I cannot rely on using `bar.x, bar.y` (populated from `foo.x, foo.y`) as unique since very nearby (in `x, y` space) `Foo` instances would be allowed to create `Bar` instances, but they shouldn't because I need to collect all `Foo`'s within `radius` to be associated with the same `Bar`.

(Part of me wonders if all this would be safe even with `get_or_create` since no `IntegrityError` would be raised even if we do end up making a `Bar` within `radius` of another - in that case is it possible to write some custom logic somewhere that will cause this to throw on any instance creation?)

Sorry if this is difficult to follow, I can try clarify in comments.

---

Minimal, simple example models for completeness:

```
class BarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def circle_search(self, x, y, radius):
        # custom SQL to filter on a distance
        return qs

class Bar(models.Model):
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    objects = BarQuerySet.as_manager()

class Foo(models.Model):
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

Comment: Can you show the logic of `circle_search`? raw SQL or Django ORM Q objects? Reason I'm asking is maybe you can create a [`Constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) that would raise an error.

Comment: It uses [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra) with some raw SQL for `select` and `where` since I require an external postgres extension to calculate my distances (they're not just x,y in reality). Not the best idea to use this, but I haven't found a better way. I had not seen Constraints before, thanks for the pointer I will look into them further.

Comment: Seems like overriding `CheckConstrint._get_check_sql` could do it. It seems to just convert a `Q` object into raw sql in there anyway.

Comment: For information, indeed just passing a string as `check` to a subclassed `CheckConstraint` class which just returns `self.check` in `_get_check_sql` seems to allow a raw sql version of a constraint. However, I have ran into the issue of subqueries not being allowed in check constraints in postgres and so will look for another solution, probably overriding `Bar.save()`.

Comment: Just wondering, have you considered using [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/) for what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding some check in `Bar.clean()` and overriding the behaviour `get_or_create` in `BarQuerySet`, specifically `_create_object_from_params`.

Seems to return expected results, although not fully tested in a race situation but as it relies almost fully on django's implementation I guess that's safer than me cooking my own method.

```
class BarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    # ...
    def _create_object_from_params(self, lookup, params, lock=False):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic(using=self.db):
                params = {k: v() if callable(v) else v for k, v in params.items()}
                obj = self.create(**params)
            return obj, True
        except IntegrityError as e:
            try:
                qs = self.select_for_update() if lock else self
                # the default action is to try to get an existing instance from
                # the lookup kwargs (but this won't necessarily exist since x and 
                # y can be slightly different):
                # return qs.get(**lookup), False

                # instead, we now just grab the nearest source, continuing to
                # the raised IntegrityError if we don't grab it for any reason:
                obj = qs.circle_search(lookup['x'], lookup['y']).first()
                if obj is not None:
                    return obj, False
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            raise e


class Bar(models.Model):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        # we only care about checking if we're creating 
        # a source, hence self._state.adding
        if self._state.adding and Bar.objects.circle_search(self.x, self.y, 1).exists():
            raise IntegrityError("existing nearby source found")
        super().clean()
    # also ensure Bar.save() calls `Bar.full_clean()` to perform this check always upon save
```

(This could perhaps have even been moved one up, to override `Bar.objects.get()`, if `x, y` are in the arguments to the filter.)

Answer (score 0):

Your queries won't raise `IntegrityError` so you can't use `get_or_create()`, which relies on that. You could write a [`Constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) so that an `IntegrityError` is raised when another row within your constraint exists. But your lookup is probably too complex to pass to `get_or_create()`, in which case you should look at the Django codebase for `get_or_create()` and replicate it yourself with your own lookup.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something, but how does this stop the race of two nearby `Foo`'s arriving concurrently and creating separate `Bar`'s without honouring the need for none within `radius` of each other? The queryset would be empty and nothing locked. Locking all `Bar` rows to create a '1 at a time' situation is not feasible from a speed standpoint.

Comment: I was thinking of querying `all()` rows first in the transaction, locking the entire table for the other call to `all()`. But that only works when actually running the query, so not very efficient. You could try to `count()` to perform the query.

Comment: I'll delete this, as it only solves it if you're able to add a `Constraint`. In that case you could look at the `get_or_create` code and replicate that (it uses `select_for_update()`).